# Where to set "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead"

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

I am getting following error while running my spark-scala program.

YarnSchedulerBackends$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 2.6GB of 2.5GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.

I have set spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead in the program while creating SparkSession.

My question is - is it ok to set "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead" while creating SparkSession or should it be passed during runtime with spark-submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` at the time of sparkSession creation. This parameter is used as amount of off-heap memory (in megabytes) to be allocated per executor. This is memory that accounts for things like VM overheads, interned strings, other native overheads, etc. This tends to grow with the executor size (typically 6-10%).

Now this allocation can only be done at the time of allocation of the executor not at the runtime.

Comment: Does this hold good for both when deployMode is cluster or client?

Comment: Also is it ok if I set this during spark-submit or set if using config while creating SparkSession?

Comment: Both essentially same, the spark submit configurations are used to create the spark session only. So you pass the config at the spark submit or use that while creating the sparksession both are same.. Passing the config at spark submit is convenient as you don't need to do code changes in case you want to change the parameters

Comment: Thanks ! I am facing a situation where I am reading all configurations from a textfile that has all configurations listed and then I pass those to SparkSession.config(key, value). But somehow those are not getting set. I have spent whole day figuring out but no clue. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you also look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576667/how-to-specify-spark-authenticate-secret-value-while-executing-spark-pgm